# Jest test Object with uuid

Tags: javascript, ts-jest

Suppose I have an object whose keys are generated with uuid and takes the shape:

```
const mapper: {[k: string]: string} = {'id1': '1', 'id2': '2', 'id3': '1', 'id4': '2'}
```

Now I am testing there are 4 ids, each id contains either 1 or 2. How to test there are exactly two 1s and two 2s?

The example for each id containing either 1 or 2:

```
Object.values(mapper).forEach(name =>
  expect(['1', '2']).toContain(name)
);
```

Comment: Count the number of 1s and 2s?